# How to refresh a wordpress widget javascript every minute

Tags: javascript, refresh

I am displaying 'now playing' on a radio website and have the javascript to show this placed in a widget.

I'd like to refresh it every minute if possible.  I'm a bit of a novice with coding so any help would be gratefully appreciated!

Coding I'm using is:

```
<span id="mav_nowplaying"></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.makeavoice.com/shoutcast2/snippets/nowplaying.php?ip=87.117.201.166&amp;port=8200&amp;streamtitle=yes&amp;streamsong=yes&amp;streamlisteners=no&amp;streammaxlisteners=no&amp;streambitrate=no&amp;streamtitlecolor=4C0099&amp;streamsongcolor=7F00FF&amp;streamlistenerscolor=FFFFFF&amp;streammaxlistenerscolor=FFFFFF&amp;streambitratecolor=FFFFFF&amp;streamtitlesize=3&amp;streamsongsize=2&amp;streamlistenerssize=-1&amp;streammaxlistenerssize=-1&amp;streambitratesize=-1" language="javascript"></script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh it? You need to provide more details.

Comment: Sorry, I mean refresh the page perhaps?  Basically the scripting shows the song playing, but doesn't update until you physically refresh the whole page.

Comment: So I'd like the widget to update every minute or so to show the correct track playing - does that make sense?